# Flat tires after relacing 3 times and 2 rims later, still keeps gokng flat

Tags: tires, wheels

My front passenger tire keeps going flat.  This is the third tire and second rim.  What is happening?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the tire shop saying? What have they done (beyond what you've stated)? Is this a new tire or use tire? Could this be someone messing with you?